Flask route params not being correctly passed when using wtf form
I have a route defined in a flask blueprint:
@bp.route('/comparison', defaults={'category':'chatarra'}, methods=['GET'])
@bp.route('/comparison/<string:category>', methods=['GET'])
def comparison(category):

    records_by_category = Record.getAllWithCategoryGroupByMonthYear(category)

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'DateMonth': [c.date for c in records_by_category],
        'Amount': [abs(c.amount) for c in records_by_category]
        })

    fig = px.bar(df, y='DateMonth', x='Amount', orientation='h', height=700)

    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    category_form = CategorySelectForm()

    category_form.name.choices = [c.name for c in Category.getAll()]

    if category_form.validate_on_submit():
            
        return redirect(url_for('main.comparison', category=category_form.name.data))
    
    return render_template('comparison.html', category_form=category_form, graphJSON=graphJSON)

also I have defined a flask-wtf form for
class CategorySelectForm(FlaskForm):
    name = SelectField('Category', validators=[InputRequired()])

here is the section for the form in the html view for the route:
        <div class="card">
            <form method="get">
                <div class="col-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">                
                    {{category_form.csrf_token }}
                    
                    {{category_form.name.label}} {{category_form.name(class_="form-select")}}
                    
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
                    <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="Poll">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

So the issue, is, if I define the form method as POST (<form method="post">), when I click submit button, the validation in the route (category_form.validate_on_submit()) properly passes the parameters to the endpoint in the url_for() function. But if I define the method as GET in the form within the HTML view, then the endpoint gets called without passing the parameters in the url_form() and instead get passed as query params (alongside the crfs token which should be hidden?) (http://127.0.0.1:5000/records/?csrf_token=######&date_start=2024-04-28&date_end=2024-04-30&submit=Submit)
My question is, which would be the correct way to pass parameters to a flask route via a get request triggered from a from within html using wtf forms? Thanks for your time.
I have tried switching the method to POST and it works, but I would rather use GET as is not triggering change in my data.

This is standard HTTP behaviour with form data submitted with POST being sent as a request body and data submitted with GET being sent as query parameters. You could merely omit the CSRF token entirely for this form as it is only of use in when server state is changed. There is also nothing wrong with using POST here as although POST requests are allowed to change server state they are not required to do so.
